# Is it possible to use Ray with Uvicorn/Blacksheep

Tags: python, ray, uvicorn, blacksheep

I want to run a Uvicorn/Blacksheep server on multiple threads. I was thinking of using Ray to do that.  Does this make any sense, or am I misunderstanding Uvicorn?

I want to start one Ray thread per core on my machine.

```
from blacksheep import Application
import uvicorn
import ray

ray.init()
app = Application()

@app.route("/")
async def home():
    return "Hello, World!"

@ray.remote
class SyncWorker:
    # Each invocation this runs a seperate thread.
    def start_server(self):
        uvicorn.run(app, host=host, port=port)
```

Comment: Have you checked ray serve? I think you can do the same thing using this https://docs.ray.io/en/master/serve/http-guide.html#serve-fastapi-http

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, what you're looking for is being deprecated. Ray team suggests to fully embed FastAPI and Serve deployments (and serve everything with `serve`).

Look at the example from their docs

```py
import ray
import requests
from fastapi import FastAPI
from ray import serve

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def f():
    return "Hello from the root!"


@serve.deployment(route_prefix="/")
@serve.ingress(app)
class FastAPIWrapper:
    pass


serve.run(FastAPIWrapper.bind())
resp = requests.get("http://localhost:8000/")
assert resp.json() == "Hello from the root!"
```

In this case `ray` takes a responsibility to serve a full application, i.e. (`uvicorn == ray.serve`).

Check out the discussion [New FastAPI HTTP Deployments running on uvicorn](https://discuss.ray.io/t/new-fastapi-http-deployments-running-on-uvicorn/3435). Read, also, new [Ray Serve](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/serve/index.html) docs.

If you still want to use `blacksheep`, you can use it as a proxy to your ray models which you request by http.